# MSI License file for Play Application

Tags: wix, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play application that I am attempting to create an MSI for.

The documentation reads that I can set the license text for the installer dialog like this;
An (optional) rtf file to display as the product license during installation. Defaults to src/windows/License.rtf

which I have added to my build.sbt file as;

wixProductLicense := "LICENSE//myLicense.rtf"

(I have tried with single slashes and a backslashes - no change)

My play application looks like;

```
APPROOT
|-app
|-LICENSE
   |- myLicense.rtf
build.sbt
```

but I get the following error;

```
error: type mismatch;  found   : String("LICENSE\\myLicense.rtf") 
required: Option[sbt.File]
(which expands to)  Option[java.io.File]
         wixProductLicense := "LICENSE\\myLicense.rtf",
```

I also tried;

wixProductLicense := Some("LICENSE\myLicense.rtf"),

but get the same error.

There isn't a SRC folder / directory in a default Play application.

Creating the path/file;
/src/windows/License.rtf

of course solves the problem - but I am hoping to avoid this "extra" path / file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you are using the wrong type. You try to set an `Option[File]` to be a String or Option of String, which is a type error.

Try

```
wixProductLicense := Some(baseDirectory.value / "LICENSE" / "myLicense.rtf")
```

Cheers,
Muki